# Optimize the time it take to read txt file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to reduce the time it takes to read a txt file. The file contains x and y coordinates like this:

```
{52.52, 13.38}
{53.55, 10.}
{48.14, 11.58}
{50.95, 6.97}
...
```

For now it take approx 0.06s to read and calculate the real position for 12000 coordinates but I would like to do it on half that time.

```
def read_coordinate_file(filename):
points = []
file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    a, b = line.strip("{}\n").split(",")
    points.append([get_x(float(b)), get_y(float(a))])
file.close()
return np.array(points)


def get_x(b, R=1):
return R*(pi*b)/180


def get_y(a, R=1):
temp = 90*pi+pi*a
return R*np.log(np.tan(temp/360))
```

If I have understod it correctly this could be done with numpy arrays. I have tried with np.loadtxt but this goes slower than my current code. Is there any way to reduce the time for this?

Comment: This is already pretty fast. You **might** get an improvement bei doing the calculations after converting to Numpy array.

Comment: Since the text file includes the `{}` the common `csv` readers will have problems.  A variation would be to just collect the `(float(b), float(a))` tuples, and do the `get_x` and `get_y` processing later on the `(N,2)` float array.  `np.log`, `np.tan` work with arrays, but are slower than the `math` equivalents when working with scalars.

Comment: You may get better advice over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't send people off to Code Review - unless you are active there and prepared to answer this question yourself.

Comment: Since I return a np.array should it go faster to use np.loadtxt and only work with np.arrays and not use lists at all?

Comment: `loadtxt` reads the raw numbers in about the same way you do - line by line, with split on delimiter.  The question is whether the added calculations are taking much time or not, compared to the file read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would definitely agree with the comments that doing all the calculations in Numpy should be faster:

```
import numpy as np
from math import pi

def read_coordinate_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        points = [tuple(map(float, line.strip("{}\n").split(','))) for line in f if line]
    arr = np.array(points, dtype=[('x','<f4'), ('y','<f4')])
    arr['x'] = arr['x'] * pi / 180
    arr['y'] = np.log(np.tan((90*pi + pi*arr['y'])/ 360))
    return arr
print(read_coordinate_file('data.txt'))
```

I don't have your data set to test with so I can't verify that it is necessarily faster, but this at least moves the calcs into Numpy.

(I left out `R` because it wasn't immediately obvious to me where you were specifying an alternate value from the default of `1`.)

Comment: For readability I'd be tempted to move the comprehension into a generator.